# View or set seed value for Random point generator

Tags: qgis, random

I have a requirement to generate random points inside polygons but this generation must be repeatable.  Is there a way to either get the seed value that the random point generator is using or insert my own?

---

Got it.  works perfectly.  I was still running Essen.  Updated and works well.

Answer (score 7):

You can edit the script to set your seed value. For example, if I want to set a seed value to the `Random points inside polygons (fixed)` tool, I can find the script in:

```
C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.16.1/apps/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/
```

Edit the script and search for `random.seed()` then insert your value (it is intially empty):

[image: Script]

(*Note: You may have to move the .py file outside the folder, edit and save the file, then insert it back to the same folder.*)

---

Example:

I run the tool to create 3 points in a polygon layer:

[image: 3 random points]

I then run the same tool to create 6 points (those highlighed in yellow are in the exact same position as when I ran it previously):

[image: 6 random points]

Comment: ... then add a new optional parameter `PARAMETER_SEED` to the script and make a pull request so you don't have to maintain your own version ;)

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn - Thanks, once I've established how to pull requests, I'll submit one =)

Comment: Very short: go to the [qgis repo](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS), click "fork", edit your copy (optionally on a separate branch), [make a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/).

Comment: Thanks heaps. Almost got it. I'm trying tomuse this method with stratified sampling. Is there another file I need to modify to get that process to be repeatable. Cheers

Comment: @joesph. Thanks so much. That was my comment above. Didn't log on properly.

Comment: @JohnLucas - Most welcome, glad it helped! And don't worry about the comment ;)